# My Armature rig slows Blender down

Tags: armature

When selecting small groups of bones in Edit Mode it runs fine, but using Pose Mode and trying to move a part of my character or trying to move the rig or character in Object Mode it lags the program a lot. I used the Rigify add-on to add in a Human metarig and the lag arose when I parented it to my character.

Comment: Sadly, that is probably just an artifact of the computer figuring out how to deform the model, when you select/move the bone.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. It lagged because my model had WAY too many tris. I heavily lowered the tris, restoring the original speed.

Comment: This is one of the reason why you should retopologize your models before rigging them. Another reason is that you cannot predict how a triangulated mesh deforms when you pose it. You probably get lots of ugly rendering artefacts in those areas.